# Cannot access sdcard directory in Android

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I am working on a small app project that calls camera.app, takes a photo and returns the photo on the screen. I can go through all the steps when the photo is a local variable. However, when I want to save it in a specific path and read it from the path, Android always warns

```
'E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/camera_app/cam_image.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)'
```

There are also warnings that I don't understand, such as

```
 E/linker: readlink('/proc/self/fd/42') failed: Permission denied [fd=42]


E/HiApp.SerializedObject: Thread-840{840} a.b(null:-1) <<< ERROR >>> read file error/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.huawei.appmarket/files/Data/.AppCheckInfo: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The computer can read the sdcard. I don't know how to debug the code

```
Button button;
ImageView imageView;
static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;
String SDPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    TextView SDCard;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bn);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    SDCard = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
    SDCard.setText(SDPath);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = getFile();
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,contentUri);
            startActivityForResult(camera_intent,CAM_REQUEST);

        }});
}

private File getFile(){
    File folder = new File(SDPath+"/camera_app");//"EVA-AL10/sdcard/camera_app" "storage/1599-2841/camera_app"
    if(!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    File image_file = new File(folder,"cam_image.jpg");
    return image_file;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    String path = SDPath+"/camera_app/cam_image.jpg";//"EVA-AL10/sdcard/camera_app/cam_image.jpg"
    imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
}
```

Updated xml:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
android:required="true"></uses-feature>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: if you are targeting SDK 23+ please make sure you have a runtime request permission.

Comment: on which version of android you are testing your app?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a permission: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: Thanks! I added the permission but the app still doesn't work. It seems like it fails to find the SD card path I set.

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest file.

You need to add these two permissions

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting api 23+ then you should add a run-time permission check. In your first launching activity you need to add this code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        checkAllPermissions();
    }
}
```

here is the method check all permission

```
private void checkAllPermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_STORAGE);
        Log.d(TAG, "checkAllPermissions: inside write external");
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_STORAGE);
        Log.d(TAG, "checkAllPermissions: inside read external");
    }}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! mActivity, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_STORAGE, and TAG aren't able to resolve. Are they all strings?

Comment: no its a constant private int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_STORAGE = 1;

Comment: mActivity is a string?or a class?

Comment: mActivity is the context object i.e private Activity mActivity; mActivity = MainActivity.this;

Comment: pls mark it as accepted if your problem solved bcz it helps others to get the right answer for any problem